# PHP - Xdebugger in Visual Studio Code detects and pauses at a specific break point correctly but F5, F11(Continue, Step Into) do not work

Tags: php, debugging, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I have a really annoying problem of debug detecting breakpoint and triggering but Step into(F11), Continue(F5) are just not working. This just started suddenly one fine day, I was working fine earlier. I might be new to visual studio code and php development. But am not a novice developer as such. This is really annoying me and I feel crippled without F5 and F11. Donno what am I missing!!!!

My setup:

1. Installed MAMP.
2. Installed Visual Studio Code.(v 1.19.2)
3. Installed PHP.
4. Installed all php extensions for visual studio code.
5. My PHP workspace debug's launch.json as follows below:

   ```
    {
   // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
   // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
   // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
       {
           "name": "Listen for XDebug",
           "type": "php",
           "request": "launch",
           "port": 9000
       },
       {
           "name": "Launch currently open script",
           "type": "php",
           "request": "launch",
           "program": "${file}",
           "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
           "port": 9000
       }
   ]
   ```

   }

My debug process:

1. Open the Php working folder using Visual Studio Code.
2. Setup breakpoints in my php code. (For example : Put breakpoints in IotSim.php file)
3. Run a local folder instance of the php server on port 8000 by typing the following in console:
     c:....\php\src\www> php -S localhost:8000
4. This starts the local php instance.
5. Press F5 in VS Code and start "Listen to Xdebug"
6. Open browser and type the following in the address bar:
     http://localhost:8000/iotsim.php/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START
7. This triggers Xdebugger listener in VS Code and pauses at the breakpoint.
8. But F11, F5,...!! nothing works. Its just stands still.  Please help.

All points from 1 to 7 above are the default process everyone does during debug I am guessing...but what is it I am doing wrong. Please help!!!

My silly and annoying work around is to remove all breakpoints, just put one breakpoint after a line which I want to check a value. See image below:
[image: The instance when breakpoint is detected but cannot Step into or Continue]

Please help!!

Comment: 1) So .. do those buttons work when breakpoint is set as on screenshot? Or they do nothing regardless where breakpoint is set? 2) Have you tested it on a simple script (as simple as assign values to 2 variables and then add those values and assign to the third variable? Same behaviour? 3) If it works fine in simple script ... what kind of URL you are requesting in that `curl_exec()` line? I mean -- is that URL is served by the same server? I'm thinking ... maybe xdebug tries to debug that call as well (depends on how xdebug is configured though) and VSC cannot handle 2 debug sessions at once.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestions. My comments for each of your question as follows 1) No the buttons too don't work when I click with mouse or use F11/F5. 2)Did create a simple script as you suggested, and it is still the same, same behaviour!! 3) Same behaviour, not able to F5/F11 or nothing happens

Comment: Wow!!! I just created a new workspace folder and just copied all the source files to the new folder and the Xdebugger just works fine.I have clicked F5 for first time, selected PHP and it generated the new launch.json and it works perfectly now!!!! I have compared both jsons, they look the same too!!! 
Logically the structure of both workspaces is just the same. Really curious what is the difference here but once I have time I will look into this and post the solution. Currently just elated that Debugger is working and I have to get back to my work

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else that encounters this - remove your Watches. If one is out of scope and returns null, it will cause continue/stepping not to work.

Comment: Great tip ! Saved me a lot of frustration. Have a good day :-)

Comment: THIS WORKS!
I've been trying to fix this for hours... Surely the extension could better handle watch variables or include a !WARNING! somewhere in its documentation.
Gah!